# Extracting a subset of attributes with JSONPath2 from two nodes of a json document

Tags: python, jsonpath

I have the following JSON document:

```
{
  "A": "A_VALUE",
  "B": {
    "C": [
      {
        "D": {
          "E": "E_VALUE1",
          "F": "F_VALUE1",
          "G": "G_VALUE1"
        },
        "H": ["01", "23" ]
      },
      {
        "D": {
          "E": "E_VALUE2",
          "F": "F_VALUE2",
          "G": "G_VALUE3"
        },
        "H": ["45", "67" ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and I would like to extract field H using a jsonpath2 expression where I specify a value for E field,
for example :

```
$..C[?(@.D.G="G_VALUE1")].H[1]
```

The code I use to parse this is the following ( jsonpath version 0.4.3 ):

```
from jsonpath2.path import Path
s='{ "A": "A_VALUE", "B": { "C": [ { "D": { "E": "E_VALUE1", "F": "F_VALUE1", "G": "G_VALUE1" }, "H": ["01", "23" ] }, { "D": { "E": "E_VALUE2", "F": "F_VALUE2", "G": "G_VALUE3" }, "H": ["45", "67" ] } ] } }"'
p = Path.parse_str("$..C[?(@.D.E=\"E_VALUE1\")].H[1]")
print ([m.current_value for m in p.match(s)])
```

output

```
[]
```

Now, if I use JsonPath evaluator on https://jsonpath.com/ I obtain the following result which is not exatly what I need

```
$..C[?(@.D.E="E_VALUE1")].H[1]
```

output

```
[23,67]
```

But If I change the expression this way than it works and I obtain what I need;

```
$..C[?(@.D.E=="E_VALUE1")].H[1]
```

output

```
[23]
```

Same results with other online evaluator such as https://codebeautify.org/jsonpath-tester

So what would be the correct jsonpath expression I should use with jsonpath2 api in order to correctly extract the two required fields ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `[*]` to access individual objects inside an array. This code works -

```py
from jsonpath2.path import Path
import json
s='{ "A": "A_VALUE", "B": { "C": [ { "D": { "E": "E_VALUE1", "F": "F_VALUE1", "G": "G_VALUE1" }, "H": ["01", "23" ] }, { "D": { "E": "E_VALUE2", "F": "F_VALUE2", "G": "G_VALUE3" }, "H": ["45", "67" ] } ] } }'
jso = json.loads(s)
p = Path.parse_str('$..C[*][?(@.D.E="E_VALUE1")].H[1]') # C[*] access each bject in the array
print (*[m.current_value for m in p.match(jso)]) # 23
```

You can refer to this example from the jsonpath2 [docs](https://jsonpath2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exampleusage.html#bookstore_test.TestBookStore.test_bookstore_examples_10)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `==` syntax.

Full disclosure:  I've never heard of jsonpath before coming across your question, but being somewhat familiar with XPath, I figured I would read about this tool.  I came across a site that can evaluate your expresssion using diffeernt implementations:  http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com.   The net result was that your expression with `=` could not be parsed by 3 of the 4 implementations.  Moreover, the Goessner implementation returned results that you weren't expecting (all C elements matched and the result was `[23,67]`.  With the `==` boolean expression, 3 of the 4 implementations provided the expected result of `[23]`.  The Nebhale implementation again complained about the expresssion.

Comment: I thought same too at first, but jsonpath2 does not support `==` syntax. It gives error `extraneous input '='` on using `==`.